# How to convert this WebSocket pattern to a Task I can await/cancel/continuewith/

Tags: websocket, async-await, task-parallel-library, ienumerable, taskcompletionsource

I have 3rd party WebSocket that I need to consume where the request is sent in one method and the response is given in another.  How can I convert this type of pattern to a more typical async/await TPL Task that will support cancellation (via token), continue with and all the other goodies.

This is what I came up with so far, although I'm not sure if it works.  I can't test it until Monday.

So here are my questions:

1. Will this work?
2. I've been reading about `TaskCompletionSource`.  Is there a better way to do any of this possibly with `TaskCompletionSource`?
3. I really don't like the lock because I know it has the potential to block for a long time but but I'm not sure how to do it any better because if I don't lock a second call to `AsyncGetPositions` could clear any positions already returned.
4. Even with the `lock` I know that if there is a timeout or cancellation that creates a problem so maybe I just remove the cancellation token.  The only other thing I can think of would be to create multiple clients that are all authenticated and ready to process a request and then manage them like a thread pool for these types of request but I'm not going to be doing that anytime soon so other than that... idk.

   ```
   private object GetPositionsLock = new object();
   private IEnumerable<Position> Positions { get; } = new List<Position>();
   private Task PositionsReturned { get; set; }
   public async Task<List<Position>> AsyncGetPositions(CancellationToken token)
   {
       try
       {
           lock (GetPositionsLock)
           {
               Positions.Clear();
               IbWebSocket.reqPositions();
               PositionsReturned = new Task(null, token, TaskCreationOptions.None);
               PositionsReturned.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
               return token.IsCancellationRequested ? null : Positions.ToList().Where(x => x.Shares != 0).ToList();
           }
       }
       catch (TimeoutException ex)
       {
           //LogTimeout
           throw;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           //LogError
           throw;
       }
   }

   ///  <summary>
   ///         Provides a position to the reqPositions() method.  When the last position has been received positionEnd() is called.
   ///  </summary>
   ///  <param name="contract"></param>
   ///  <param name="value"></param>
   ///  <param name="account"></param>
   public void position(string account, Contract contract, double value)
   {
       try
       {
           Positions.Concat(new Position(account, contract, value));
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           //LogError
           throw;
       }
   }

   /// <summary>
   ///     Indicates all the positions have been transmitted.
   /// </summary>
   public void positionEnd()
   {
       PositionsReturned = Task.CompletedTask;
   }
   ```

Comment: Not sure where to start. `AsyncGetPositions` isn't even doing asyn calls (I don't see any `await` statement). Furthermore, you don't actually start the `Task`. Also, what's the socket interface? How do the events look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will this work?

No. You [shouldn't use the `Task` constructor](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html), use `lock` with `async` code, or [mix blocking with asynchronous code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming).

> I've been reading about TaskCompletionSource. Is there a better way to do any of this possibly with TaskCompletionSource?

Yes, that's the type to use for this scenario.

> I really don't like the lock because I know it has the potential to block for a long time but but I'm not sure how to do it any better because if I don't lock a second call to AsyncGetPositions could clear any positions already returned.

I recommend getting this working *first*, and *then* handling the additional requirement of reentrancy. Each of those are hard enough on their own.

---

What you want to do is have a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` and complete it when `positionEnd` is invoked. For simplicity, start without reentrancy concerns and without the `CancellationToken`. Once you fully understand `TaskCompletionSource<T>`, then you can add complexity:

```
private List<Position> Positions { get; } = new();
private TaskCompletionSource<List<Position>> PositionsReturned { get; set; }
public Task<List<Position>> AsyncGetPositions()
{
  Positions.Clear();
  PositionsReturned = new();
  IbWebSocket.reqPositions();
  return PositionsReturned.Task;
}

public void position(string account, Contract contract, double value)
{
  Positions.Add(new Position(account, contract, value));
}

public void positionEnd()
{
  PositionsReturned.TrySetResult(Positions);
}
```