# How to best use TaskCompletionSource with SemaphoreSlim

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, semaphore, taskcompletionsource

This is an evolution of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66718890/2884229).  To recap, I have 3rd party WebSocket that I need to consume where the request is sent in one method and the response is given in another.  I'm attempting to convert this to a `Task`.

I read [this MSDN Magazine article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) which shows an example of using a `SemaphoreSlim` to control entry but my case isn't quite the same and I'm not sure what the best thing to do is.

I could put the `SemaphoreSlim.Release()` in the `finally` block of `GetPositionsAsync()` as shown in the article but if there were an error then the finally could get called before `positionEnd()` which would cause an error in `GetPositionsAsync()` if there was another thread waiting for the semaphore.  On the other hand if I put the `SemaphoreSlim.Release()` in `positionEnd()` can I reliably assume that `GetPositionsAsync()` will return the proper result?  I'm worried that if the release happens a thread waiting for the semaphore might call `Positions.Clear()` before the other thread saves the value of `Positions` to `result`.  So really the same concern either way.  Which is better or is there another way to protect this problem from happening all together?

This is what I have so far...

```cs
private TaskCompletionSource<List<Position>> PositionsTaskSource { get; set; }
private readonly SemaphoreSlim PositionsMutex = new(1, 1);

public async Task<List<Position>> GetPositionsAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await PositionsMutex.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        Positions.Clear();
        PositionsTaskSource = new();
        IbWebSocket.reqPositions();
        var result = await PositionsTaskSource.Task;
        //Write to Trace Log here
        return result;
    }
    finally
    {
        //I could put the Release here as shown in the article
        //PositionsMutex.Release(); 
    }
}

/// <summary>
///        Provides a position to the reqPositions() method.  When the last position has been received positionEnd() is called.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="account"></param>
/// <param name="contract"></param>
/// <param name="value"></param>
public void position(string account, Contract contract, double value)
{
    Positions.Add(new Position(account, contract, value));
}

/// <summary>
///     Indicates all the positions have been transmitted.
/// </summary>
public void positionEnd()
{
    PositionsTaskSource.TrySetResult(Positions))
    PositionsMutex.Release();
}
```

Comment: Could you please share with us the code of the `PositionsTaskSource` and `PositionsMutex` ?

Comment: My bad, added them.

Comment: Could you please share with us the consuming code as well?

Comment: The consuming code would call  `var test = await GetPositionsAsync()`

Comment: Sorry I was not specific enough. How and when the `positionEnd` will be called? It would be nice to see how these two methods are being called to understand how these two signalling mechanism (`SemaphoreSlim`, `TaskCompletionSource`)  are triggered.

Comment: They are both part of the 3rd party code.  I have no control over how/when they are called other than the fact that they are part of the interface that my class implements.  The way it works is when I call `IbWebSocket.reqPositions()` then the 3rd party code will call `position()` once for each position and finally `positionEnd` after the last position has been called.  It's up to me to do what I want in the bodies of those two methods.  I find this pattern completely useless so I'm trying to abstract from it so I can get the positions in a more typical way i.e. as a `Task<List<Position>>>`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call `PositionsMutex.Release();` in `positionEnd()`.  Once `positionEnd()` sets the task result, `GetPositionsAsync` will continue and ultimately release the semaphore, thus allowing the next caller to re-enter.

Comment: Can you explain more please, because that's not what I understand from the documentation... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-5.0.

Comment: @LorneCash, the point is that SemaphoreSlim requires you to call `WaitAsync()` when you want to restrict access and `Release()` when you want to let others enter the protected code.  Therefore, when you call `PositionsTaskSource.TrySetResult(Positions))`, your `var result = await PositionsTaskSource.Task;` will continue and your code will get to the `finally` block and  'PositionsMutex.Release(); '

Answer (score 0):

As it was stated by the MSDN article and by [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383426/nick) as well it is enough to call the `Release` inside the `GetPositionsAsync`'s `finally` block.

In order to better articulate your intent I would suggest a slight change in your code:

- Instead of using `TaskCompletionSource<List<Position>>`
- I would suggest to use `TaskCompletionSource<object>`:

```cs
private TaskCompletionSource<object> PositionsHasBeenPopulated;
private readonly SemaphoreSlim GetPositionAsyncMutex = new(1, 1);

public async Task<List<Position>> GetPositionsAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await GetPositionAsyncMutex.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        Positions.Clear();
        PositionsHasBeenPopulated = new();
        IbWebSocket.reqPositions();
        
        await PositionsHasBeenPopulated.Task;
        return Positions;
    }
    finally
    {
        GetPositionAsyncMutex.Release();
    }
}


public void position(string account, Contract contract, double value)
    => Positions.Add(new Position(account, contract, value));

public void positionEnd()
    => PositionsHasBeenPopulated.TrySetResult(null);
```

- The `GetPositionAsyncMutex` limits the concurrent calls to one

  - I would suggest to use another overload where you either specify the [timeout in milliseconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_SemaphoreSlim_WaitAsync_System_Int32_) or you can provide a [cancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_SemaphoreSlim_WaitAsync_System_Int32_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) as well
- The `PositionsHasBeenPopulated` is used only for signalling

  - You can consider `TaskCompletionSource<object>` as the async version of `ManualResetEvent`